# Is it possible to add an entries field to recurring events that can be changed per occurrence?

Tags: craft3, plugin-solspacecalendar

An event in Solspace Calendar that repeats weekly should have an [entries field](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/entries-fields.html), that can be changed per single occurrence. E.g. Tuesday’s evening class is usually tought by teacher A, except next week, where it’s going to be teacher B (both teachers have an entry I’d like to link to in the event’s popover).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Calendar's event recurrences are only simulated/inflated by a repeat rule for the main event. Since there is no database entry for each recurrence, there's unfortunately no way to achieve something like this at this time.